# JavaFX should or must or an alternative for new coming developers?

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm a newbie in Swing development. But now I see with Java8 JavaFX is becoming more and more important and there are even some components like html5 browser that aren't available in Swing. Personally I feel humiliated that I should learn so much about AWT/Swing/JavaFX ... to be able to create a fairly desktop application in Java. Even I find using them more difficult rather than VCL than I'd seen in Delphi.

I wonder if I should master JavaFX or Swing or both to be able to create good desktop applications with Java or they are only alternatives? I feel that in an early future(maybe 2016 with Java9) nobody will start a new Java application using Swing unless the developers wouldn't be competent in JavaFX.

I searched a lot about JavaFX in stackoverflow and the Internet but most of the found stuff are out of date and I think that there needs a new answer to this question.

Comment: *"I feel that in an early future(maybe 2016 with Java9) nobody will start a new Java application using Swing"*  People were starting new projects in AWT long after Swing was available.  What makes you think Java-FX will be any different?

Comment: Maybe they're development team weren't competent in using Swing or they needed to use the code also for making applets or they had judged badl. Anyway now quite nobody uses AWT for desktop application. At least I find no point to use AWT in spite of Swing. On the other hand many minor less experienced companies might make wrong decisions when they select the technology. Now doing a serious  complicated project in AWT instead of Swing looks to me like using an abacus for calculating logarithm & sinus!

Comment: *"Swing or they needed to use the code also for making applets.."*  You've never heard of [`JApplet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html)?

Comment: Thanks. I never new about JApplet and I thought that AWT is the unique solution. But doing a search in Java version history I see that JApplet was introduced in Java 1.4(2002) where Swing was integrated in Java core classes in Java1.2(1998). And Swing might have been already elementary without having many written libraries. Up to 2016 we will have 8 years passed since the integration of JavaFX in Java!

Comment: Simple answer: you should learn JavaFX and forget about everything else. Trust me.